# behavior:smooth param breaks window.scroll in keyboard event in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events, keyboard-events

I am pulling my hair out because for some reason when I pass `behavior: smooth` as a parameter to `window.scroll`, the function stops working altogether in Chrome. Without `behavior:smooth` it scrolls as expected. I'm pretty sure this is a Chrome bug, but I've used `behavior:smooth` elsewhere without issue, so I'm wondering what's special about the config on this page which is causing the problem. Here's the set-up, which will hopefully allow you to reproduce:

I have a document with several viewport-sized divs like so:

html:

```
<body>
    <div class="slide" data-ind="0"></div>
    <div class="slide" data-ind="1"></div>
    <div class="slide" data-ind="2"></div>
</body>
```

css:

```
.slide{
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  border-bottom:1px solid black;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

I'm trying to use an event listener to scroll to a slide when you press an arrow key, like so:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown',function(){
      if(event.key=='ArrowRight'){
        let el=document.querySelector('.slide[data-ind="1"]');
        let dist=el.offsetTop;
          window.scroll({
            top:dist,
            left:0,
            behavior:'smooth'
          })
      }
    })
```

---

**Update:** Some more testing has made it clear that the bug only happens when `window.scroll` is used within a keyboard event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by adding `event.preventDefault();` to the keyboard event. Still unclear if this is intended/standard behavior, as Firefox had no such issue even without adding this line.